# VBA to programmatically fix "errored" cells?

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm having a bit of trouble with dates. I've read a lot about it and it seems pretty common that dates format weird.

What's happening with mine is when I bring data from an xlsx file or csv file into my own workbook (via a vba load macro) the dates become formatted as text. The load macro just opens the desired file, copies and pastes all rows into the current book, then closes that file.

I checked my source file, all dates are formatted correct - dd/mm/yyyy and display correctly in the source xlsx and csv files. When I bring the data in, the dates become formatted as text and all you see is for example: `40246` which is really: `09/03/2010`.

I checked my file, they are all stored as date. I've tried to formatted as number, text, special, all variations, and then changing back to date and nothing happens.

each cell in the column (it's only 1 column) has the green error indicator, and the info says "this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe", but it's neither. I made sure there no apostrophe in my excel or the source. but, if i click "Convert to number" on that error, and then change the formatting back to date, it fixes.

I'd like to do that in code, take the entire column, convert to number, and then change to date. but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

I've tried changing the format, like: `ActiveCell.numberformat = "0.00"` (I just tried with 1 cell for practise) but that didn't clear the error, and when I changed it back to date nothing happened. I tried recording a macro of me clicking "Convert to number" in the error box but there was nothing in the code. Is there a vba command for fixing errored cells? I know theres an `iserror` (or something like that) function to tell if the cell has an error but I don't know what command to use to actually fix the error.

Any suggestions?

If I highlight the entire column, and click "Convert to number" in the error, it converts the entire column, at which point I can convert to date which fixes it, so thats what I'd like the macro to do.. I don't want to have to run over and fix it every time a user has that issue (and I don't feel confident I could have them do it themselves, whixch would really be the easiest)

[image]

notice the little green indicator, and there it says "convert to number" which I can do and then change format to date after, but it's weird how there's no code in the recorded macro when I click convert to number.

### Edit

loading code:

```
openfnameandpath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File To Be Opened") 'get file path
        dim openfnameandpath as string
        dim loadworkbook as workbook
        dim numrows as long, numcols as long

        openfnameandpath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File To Be Opened") 'get file path

        Set loadWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(openfnameandpath)

        loadWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate 'in case a different sheet was active
        numrows = Cells.find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        numcols = Cells.find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

        loadWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1", Cells(numRows, numCols)).Copy   Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) =

        loadWorkbook.Close False
```

I cut it down to that and the problem still exists.

Comment: Something is wrong with your VBA load macro, can you share the code?

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031447/green-corner-in-cell/21045436#21045436

Comment: Posted my load code, I've cut it down to exactly what I've posted and the problem exists. Cant see how anythign there would affect this..

Comment: somcoe your answer works awsome. I was just missing the `.value = .value` part... its stupid you have to include that. So to finish it off all I had to do was add `.numberformat = "dd/mm/yyy"` at the end which changed it to date afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your cells and run:

```
Sub DateFixer()
    Dim r As Range, d As Date, v As String
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        d = CDate(CLng(v))
        r.Clear
        r.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        r.Value = d
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: this works nice when I add `screenupdating = false` and an if statement to check for blanks (I wish there werent any but I'm never that lucky) with anywhere from 50k to 200k rows, it takes a while without the screenupdating bit

Comment: **Good job!**  I am glad you wee able to adapt the code to your needs and update it to improve its performance!

Comment: I think you're one of the first people I've ever had give me a "way to go" comment.. maybe a few others.. but not many.. day = made, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Dates in a CSV have to be formatted as #01/12/2014# - with the octothorpes (#) surrounding the date.  That drove me insane till I found out about it.

The other option (if you can't control the CSV) is to use datevalue() to convert the information. If the dates are in column a, create a new column B with =DateValue(A1), then copy column B, and "paste value" into column A, and then delete column B

Comment: Doesnt work.. I tried doing it by inserting a new column like you suggested, I also went as far as putting: `=DATEVALUE("40246")` and it didnt work. both times i just get the #VALUE error. If I put in the date: `=DATEVALUE(09/03/2010")` I get the numbers: `40246` lol but not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

figured I'd add another solution that works well.. found this while screwing around. this formula: `=Text(K2, "dd/mm/yyyy")` worked nice as well. so I adapted it into a macro that works nice too:

```
Sub dateFixer3()

    Dim format As String                          'added after

    format = InputBox("Please Enter Date Format") 'added after

    application.screenupdating = false

    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert

    Cells(2, ActiveCell.column).Activate

    'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Text(rc[1], ""dd/mm/yyyy"")"

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Text(rc[1], """ & format & """)" ' added after

    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 'copies formula for entire column

    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Copy

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'paste values in original column

    'ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).EntireColumn.Delete xlShiftToLeft 'delete inserted column

    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'added after

    application.screenupdating = true

End Sub
```

to use: activate any cell in the desired column then run the macro.
it does use active cell a few times, but only `.activate` once to make sure that the second row (save room for a heading) is the one that it's working with instead of whatever random row.

*note: `application.screenupdating = false` / `application.screenupdating = true` at beginning / end isn't **necessary** but it makes it so the user doesn't see the whole insert,copy,paste,delete business (this scares my users, lol)

### edit

note the comments, I added a few lines and commented out a couple. The updated code allows the user to enter whatever format they want. It can be looked up from the "format cells" option which has many standard formats. but this way when run it can be sometimes dd/mm/yyyy or maybe they prefer yyyy/mm/dd etc... also, it leaves the original data so the users can review the changes and then decide to kep and delete original, or not keep and delete the new column

the macro can actually be used in place of right clicking and using format cells, to change format to anything (number, text, general, etc...) if a user wants the entire column formatted.

Comment: updated to be more dynamic and a little safer (keeps original data)